# How to make my box model is well displayed?

Tags: border, margin, css

I don't understand why the margin-top CSS property is not displayed in my divs with class `.inner`. Moreover I don't understand why the border of my first `.inner` div overflows his parent.
I thought about margin collapsing and I tried a lot of things but nothing works.

Here is the codepen : http://codepen.io/guduf/pen/gbWXoG

Thank you for your help.

Comment: always post the relevant code in the question itself....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They need to be `display:inline-block` in order for margin to take effect.

[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mymqXM)

Comment: @GabrielSNM thank for your awsers. it works. do you know a way for not using inline-block property because this is not supported by all browsers ?

Comment: These days it is [very well supported](http://caniuse.com/inline-block). Are you targetting IE6 or 7?

Answer (score 2):

A span is an inline element and behaves that way.
Try setting to it "display: inline-block;"

For old browsers you can try:

```
display:-moz-inline-stack;
display:inline-block;
zoom:1;
*display:inline;
```

(http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/)